# How to put bash variables in quotes

Tags: linux, bash

```
DMIDECODE=$cmd_.dmidecode
UNAME=$cmd_.uname
HOSTNAME=$cmd_.hostname
```

i want to write a script which could put these variables in double quotes in all the files present in a directory or its sub directories.for instance:

```
DMIDECODE="$cmd_.dmidecode"
UNAME="$cmd_.uname"
```

I am a sort of a beginner but i have tried my hand at various things in solving this problem.I tried to write regex for the above variables and then enclose variable value in double quotes this.
The regex i wrote was
`^(?!.[a-z])(?!.[0-9]).+[=][$].*$`
The thing i kept in mind was that variable should start with a capital letter followed by = and $ symbol followed by anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`, like this:

```
sed 's/^\([[:upper:]][[:upper:]_]\{1,\}=\)\(.*\)[[:blank:]]*/\1"\2"/' file.sh
```

Explanation:

```
^            # begin of the line
\(           # start of capturing group 1
[[:upper:]]  # uppercase character
[[:upper:]]  # uppercase or underscore character
\{1,\}       # one or more times
=            # the literal =
\)           # end of capturing group 1
\(.*\)       # capturing group 2 contains the value
[[:blank:]]* # optional white space at the end of the line
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple alternative that uses a backreference to check to the end of line could be:

```
sed -i 's/[=]\([$].*$\)/="\1"/' filename
```

Which using the `-i` option performs the replacement in place. A short test calling the above on your sample file produced:

```
DMIDECODE="$cmd_.dmidecode"
UNAME="$cmd_.uname"
HOSTNAME="$cmd_.hostname"
```

Comment: It's a bit too unspecific. This would replace `echo "$foo"` by `echo ""$foo""` for example.

Comment: Yes, I like how you tailored yours, and it should be noted that this is a very simple approach based on the example files, and additional guards are needed if the files hold complete scripts, and are not just variable/value files use to source as configs. I added the `[=]` to insure it was an assignment taking place, but all those caveats would still apply.